# Why "that is to say"

Tags: expressions

This sounds terribly British. And very wordy. Where did this phrase come from, and is it any different from plain old "say"?

Comment: It is different from plain old "say".  That is to say, I can't just haul off and say "say" and have you know that I'm about to reword or explain what I just said, as opposed to, say, stating an alternative or an example.

Comment: Have a look at this Google ngram and see if it answers your questions https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=that+is+to+say%3Aeng_us_2009%2Cthat+is+to+say%3Aeng_gb_2009&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthat%20is%20to%20say%3Aeng_us_2009%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthat%20is%20to%20say%3Aeng_gb_2009%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It's a [reformulatory pragmatic marker](http://www.hrelp.org/events/seminars/abstracts/urgelles_abstract.pdf) / sentence connector. 'Say' is usually used to mean 'for example / maybe'  (Let's try a new approach – say going by mule) or 'in the region of' [3 miles].

Comment: i know my question is poorly worded and may be rejected by the mods. but given the responses i've seen thus far, i'd like to repair the question and keep it alive. thanks for all the answers!

Comment: Italians use one word [**cioè**](http://www.wordreference.com/iten/cio%C3%A8) to express the same meaning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase "That is to say" has been around since 1200, according to OED.

> ?c1200   *Ormulum* (Burchfield transcript) l. 10085   He shollde itt hæwenn..att te treowwess rote, Þatt iss to seggenn..Rihht att tatt follkess ende.

They also refer to the French equivalent *C'est à dire.*

It is different to *say* because it's used differently.

> (a) Used to introduce a more explicit or intelligible restatement of a preceding expression, esp. to gloss one taken from a foreign language or a different variety of English. Later also used to introduce a plain, unvarnished statement of a fact which a preceding expression misrepresents or euphemistically veils.
>
> (b)  Introducing more detailed information or a specific example: to be specific; namely.

These might have examples of

- Ephphatha! That is to say, Be opened!
- He disappeared behind a bush; that is to say, he relieved himself; *that* is to say, he peed.
- You will need a tool, that is to say, a spade.

You couldn't replace any of those with *say.*
*Say* on its own means something like "Let's guess at":

> We'll need, say, ninety of those.

Comment: i guess the "Þatt iss to seggen" bit is the phrase "that is to say"